# remove a column as index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and I already used .pivot to creat the df. And now my df is same as this:

[![df that I have][1]][1]

I want to remove the 'time_hour' and create another df. I am using the reset_index and this is the results. However, I dont want a column with name time_hour. Could you please help me with that? Thanks
[![this is the df I want without the column time-hour][2]][2]

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). You might need to use `print(df)` to make sure the formatting is right.

Comment: `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`  In your second picture, 'time_hour' is the column header axis name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html),

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

'time_hour' is the column header axis name.